# Assigning/joining tabulated data to features in MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo, csv, excel

I am not a MapInfo user, but I have been asked whether that software can assign/join tabulated data to GIS features like buildings, roads and watercourses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a point from CSV file in MapInfo, you need to do the following:

1. Go to `File -> Open`
2. Change the format of the file from (tab) to (csv)
3. Select the CSV file that you want. This procedure will open CSV file as table not point.
4. To plot the X,Y as point, go to `Table -> Create Points`
5. Select the field that represents X coordinate and the field the represents Y coordinate, and then select the target projection, then click OK.
6. To see the points, go to `Window -> Map Window`

You didn't specify what type of join you need. If it is a spatial join, there is function can do similar to spatial join called `Update Column`, and you can find it from `Table -> Update Column`. You can refer to this question [Is it possible to join points to a polygon in MapInfo Professional v10.0?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/122792/63384) for more information. But if you want to join based on attribute table, you can refer to this video tutorial on [How to Get Data from One Table to Another Using Joins](http://www.pbinsight.com/support/education/video-tutorials/detail/joining-tables/).

Comment: The tutorial "video tutorial on How to Get Data from One Table to Another Using Joins." was what I was looking for.